# How to display website link, facebook & twitter icon in QR code using phpqrcode?

Tags: php, facebook, twitter

I would like to display website link, facebook & twitter icons.

I could display any one of the above fields (links only not fb and twitter icons)

```
QRcode::png($website);
QRcode::png($facebook);
QRcode::png($twitter);
```

but I want to display all combinedly like below

Website: http://example.com/

[ Facebook Icon ]  [Twitter Icon]

Comment: What makes you think that would even be possible? AFAIK QR codes contain _one_ simple text string – what to make of that (whether f.e. to treat/recognize it as a URL) is totally up to the QR code reader.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I want to make users freely visit website or facebook or twitter link with out typing anything in the address bar so it could save a lot of time for the users.

Comment: Only possibility I see for that is to have the QR code point to a simple page that offers these three options, “go to website – visit Facebook – visit Twitter”